# Some Matplotlib plots are blank/incomplete when run in dask (parallel)?

Tags: matplotlib, dask

Some plots are showing up partially drawn. Looks like there is some global state that needs to be locked on?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import dask
import os
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(processes=False)

def oneplot(x):
    fig = plt.figure(num=f'{x}')
    ax = fig.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.plot(np.random.randn(100))
    plt.savefig(os.path.expanduser(f'~/test_{x}.png'))

def test():
    d = [client.submit(oneplot, i) for i in range(10)]
    return d
```

Comment: The image you show is typical in cases you have an error halfway through creating the figure, e.g. if during y-axis creation an error occurs, the x axis is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue when working with dask and matplotlib. I solved it using `fig.savefig(...)` instead of using `plt.savefig(...)`. It might work for you as well.