# Matplotlib incorrect X & Y-axis despite correct data

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-datareader

My code creates 4 stock graphs (data taken from yahoo with pandas datareader) with matplotlib. The problem i SOMETIMES get is the X & Y-axis on the first graph created in the sequence of 4 graphs being created one after the other looks like this:

[image]

Matplotlib scales it entirely wrong, the numbers given to it are not years ranging from 1970 to 2020, It is only given 5 days. But as stated earlier it only sometimes happens and when the code creates the other 3 graphs there are absolutely no problems. I believe this is due to some issue happening when it creates a graph that ranges from 5-10 dollars and then quickly another graph that ranges from 50-100 dollars. I do have a time sleep between every graph being created but it doesn't seem to work.

I also can't scale it manually every time because the code has to create graphs of various stocks with various ranges on the axis.

```
#Libraries
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
date = datetime.date.today()

def Graphmaker(ticker, start, end, interval):
    stock_data = web.DataReader(ticker, data_source = "yahoo", start = start, end = end)        #Gets information
    plt.plot(stock_data['Close'])               #Plots
    plt.autoscale()
    plt.axis('off')             #Removes axis
    graph = plt.gcf()
    #
    plt.switch_backend('agg')
    #
    plt.draw()
    #plt.show()
    date = datetime.date.today()
    file_name = "graph_" + ticker + "_" + interval + "_day_graph_" + str(date) + ".png"
    graph.savefig('Data/test/' + file_name, dpi=100)           #Saves graph, Adds the graph image to be tested which later gets moved to 'train'
    plt.clf()                       #Without this the graphs stack on each other and create incorrect lines
    return(file_name)       #Passing the file name back to main which gets passed to predictor
```

Comment: Present the code that is currently being challenged.

Comment: [Are images generated in other applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57502510/8881141)

Comment: @Mr.T No, it doesn't

Comment: Have you checked what `stock_data` contained in cases where the graph is incomplete? Maybe ticker, start date, or end date were not in the correct format or the download was interrupted? Can you provide an example of how you call your function `Graphmaker(ticker, start, end, interval)`? Does the problem occur randomly with the same input or is it reproducible for a specific input?

Comment: You also mention that your code creates four graphs. Where does this happen?

Comment: Your code has been expanded to [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lkmQ8wmUHNB3UzNViVbqZPVl_WKpA6MA?usp=sharing). You get a graph with price only and each axis and frame removed. It is quite different from the image you posted. Is the version you are using up to date?

Comment: I will disable the Colab link once you have verified my comment.

Comment: Did you try to call `plt.switch_backend('agg')` at the start of the code instead of in the middle?  Or leaving it out entirely? The manual for [plt.switch_backend()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend.html) tells *"Close all open figures and set the Matplotlib backend."*